# Ionic app does not remove local data after uninstalling

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, sharedpreferences, ionic4

I have found a solution for Android but not able to get one for iOS.

- I logged into my app
- Perform some tasks that save data in local storage
- Go to Home and uninstall the app
- Install App again
- All previously stored data reappear

It should remove all data upon uninstallation.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Cordova, add the following in your `config.xml`-

### For iOS

Inside `<platform name="ios">`-

```xml
<preference name="BackupWebStorage" value="none" />
```

Default value is `cloud`. https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/config_ref/index.html

### For Android

Inside `<platform name="android">`-

```xml
<edit-config file="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application">
    <application android:allowBackup="false" android:fullBackupContent="false" />
</edit-config>
```

Comment: I have already added this in my config.xml but still its not working. Every time i reinstall the app it fetch the cache from previously installed

Comment: Since previous the data were synced to the cloud, it might be the case that the data is not getting deleted from the cloud even after applying the new setting. To eliminate this, can you change the bundle/package id of the app and try with that

Comment: I have tried it with multiple bundle ids but it's still not working

Comment: For ios BackupWebStorage will only works if its being set to none from the beginning and no data is syced yet. also there might be some other cases where you can check if keychain storing the data or not.