# Storage not being cleared when uninstalling Capacitor App (iOS)

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, capacitor

I've made a cross-platform app using Ionic and Capacitor but when the user uninstalls the app on iOS and re-downloads the saved data is still available, rather than it being a fresh open.

I've found this solution for Cordova [Ionic app does not remove local data after uninstalling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67091598/ionic-app-does-not-remove-local-data-after-uninstalling)

But I cannot find the equivalent for Capacitor as Capacitor moved away from Cordovas *config.xml* https://capacitorjs.com/docs/basics/configuring-your-app